# SQL Insert Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one called `orders`, the other, `orders_archive`. I have some items marked "item Complete" that I want to get into the `orders` table, but I'm having issue with it. Can someone point me in the right direction? My `OrderNumber` field is an identity seed, the numbers I'm inserting are not in the table. I don't know if that makes a difference or not.

```sql
Insert INTO Orders VALUES (OrderNumber, [Church Name], CustomerID, [Date], ShippingAddress, ShippingCity, ShippingState, ShippingZip, ToBeShippedBY, Freight, Terms, SpecialInstructions, 
  SalesRep, OrderRecievedBY, PaymentType, PaymentAccount, PaymentEXPDate, PaymentCCV, PaymentNameonCard, PaymentBillingAdd, PaymentBillingCity, 
  PaymentBillingState, PaymentBillingZip, PaymentsameasChurchAdd, Item1NO, Item1Desc, Item1QTY, Item1Price, Item2NO, Item2Desc, Item2QTY, Item2Price, 
  Item3NO, Item3Desc, Item3QTY, Item3Price, Item4NO, Item4Desc, Item4QTY, Item4Price, Item5NO, Item5Desc, Item5QTY, Item5Price, Item6NO, Item6Desc, 
  Item6QTY, Item6PRice, Item7NO, Item7Desc, Item7QTY, Item7Price, Item8NO, Item8Desc, Item8QTY, Item8Price, [Office Approved], EmailContact, 
  ENTERontoSERVERFILE, PreparePO, SendPOtoManufacture, CopyTaxExempt, ScanDOCS, BusinessUnit, SalesTax, Notes, OrderStatus, AuthNUM, TaxExempt, 
  ItemDamaged, MiscNotes, StainColor, Framecolor, Silvervein, [Tracking Number], Deposit, SENT_Receipt, Prepared_PO, Sent_PO, Created_File_ON_Server, 
  Copy_Tax_forms_to_acctng, ChangefromPAYNENTPENDING, ScanMISCDocs, Process_Payment, ConfirmONServer, CheckINVENTORY, EnterIntoBooks, 
  PlacedIntoFilingCabinet, GSTOCK, DONTSHIPBEFOREDATE, Vendor, Item1weight, Item2weight, Item3weight, Item4weight, Item5weight, Item6weight, Item7weight, 
  Item8weight, TruckNumber, ShipDate, DeliverDate, Customer, ActualQuote, PersonQuotedActual, ShipName, HeaterSerialNum
FROM dbo.Orders_ARCHIVE
WHERE (OrderStatus LIKE 'Order Complete'))
```

Comment: So, you want to only the items marked "item complete" in the orders_archive table to be put into the orders table?

Comment: can you please tells us more about "number i'm inserting are not in the table."? sorry i am not seeing what is real problem here..

Comment: yes thats correct, Im missing some orders from the main table, i made a copy of the table and called it orders_archive, but now they want to see everything again.

Comment: Im getting this error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: Thinking my syntax is wrong somehow?? Im not sure thats why Im asking for help on it. I think Im doing it wrong.

Comment: @gabrielVa Yes, you haven't ended your parenthesis. You do: `VALUES (... FROM ...`.

Comment: If you RDBMS is SQL server google IDENTITY_INSERT

Answer (score 2):

Change it to this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Orders ON

INSERT INTO Orders
SELECT <columns>
FROM Orders_ARCHIVE
WHERE OrderStatus LIKE '%Order Complete%'

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Orders OFF
```

Using the "VALUES" keyword prohibits the use of FROM and JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You cant insert into an identity field

on sql server you can turn on identity insert which will allow you to insert into identity fields:
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT Orders_ARCHIVE ON

then turn it back on again
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT Orders_ARCHIVE ON

This is not a great plan though as you could create duplicate ids.  If you don't need the archive id then just pull OrderNumber field off your insert statement.

```
Insert INTO Orders 
SELECT OrderNumber, [Church Name], CustomerID, [Date], ShippingAddress, ShippingCity, ShippingState, ShippingZip, ToBeShippedBY, Freight, Terms, SpecialInstructions, 
  SalesRep, OrderRecievedBY, PaymentType, PaymentAccount, PaymentEXPDate, PaymentCCV, PaymentNameonCard, PaymentBillingAdd, PaymentBillingCity, 
  PaymentBillingState, PaymentBillingZip, PaymentsameasChurchAdd, Item1NO, Item1Desc, Item1QTY, Item1Price, Item2NO, Item2Desc, Item2QTY, Item2Price, 
  Item3NO, Item3Desc, Item3QTY, Item3Price, Item4NO, Item4Desc, Item4QTY, Item4Price, Item5NO, Item5Desc, Item5QTY, Item5Price, Item6NO, Item6Desc, 
  Item6QTY, Item6PRice, Item7NO, Item7Desc, Item7QTY, Item7Price, Item8NO, Item8Desc, Item8QTY, Item8Price, [Office Approved], EmailContact, 
  ENTERontoSERVERFILE, PreparePO, SendPOtoManufacture, CopyTaxExempt, ScanDOCS, BusinessUnit, SalesTax, Notes, OrderStatus, AuthNUM, TaxExempt, 
  ItemDamaged, MiscNotes, StainColor, Framecolor, Silvervein, [Tracking Number], Deposit, SENT_Receipt, Prepared_PO, Sent_PO, Created_File_ON_Server, 
  Copy_Tax_forms_to_acctng, ChangefromPAYNENTPENDING, ScanMISCDocs, Process_Payment, ConfirmONServer, CheckINVENTORY, EnterIntoBooks, 
  PlacedIntoFilingCabinet, GSTOCK, DONTSHIPBEFOREDATE, Vendor, Item1weight, Item2weight, Item3weight, Item4weight, Item5weight, Item6weight, Item7weight, 
  Item8weight, TruckNumber, ShipDate, DeliverDate, Customer, ActualQuote, PersonQuotedActual, ShipName, HeaterSerialNum
FROM dbo.Orders_ARCHIVE
WHERE (OrderStatus LIKE 'Order Complete')
```

Your insert statement was incorrect you dont use the values clause when your doing a select.

Comment: Actually, you can: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Actually you can using SET IDENTITY_INSERT INSERT in sql server, and in something like mySQL you can 'overpower' auto-increment columns by providing  a value.